# Steps in writing animation doesn't work for short words

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to replicate this effect https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/YzxKGpa but the problem that i have is that when i use this effect in shorter words/phrases if i'm not using step it works but the border/cursor goes way beyond at looks weird and if i use steps lower than 25/23 the animation skips frames and does the animation writting multiple characters at the same time.

Also in the last div and class, `delayed-animation` how can i hide the border that acts like the cursor when the animation hasn't started. Kinda like what i did to hide it when it ends writting.

Here is the code with different examples in a codepen: https://codepen.io/matiB/pen/abVEooL

```css
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: none;
  }
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  clear: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}

.return {
  padding-left: 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 3s steps(9, end) forwards;
  width: 0;
}

.return-without-step {
  padding-left: 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 3s forwards;
  width: 0;
}

.working-steps {
  padding-left: 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 2s steps(43, end) forwards;
  width: 0%;
}

.working-steps-limit {
  padding-left: 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 2s steps(21, end) forwards;
  width: 0%;
}

.delayed-animation {
  padding-left: 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 2s steps(21, end) forwards;
  width: 0%;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
```

```html
<div class="return">
  <h1 style="color: purple">return ( </h1>
</div>

<div class="return-without-step">
  <h1 style="color: purple">return ( </h1>
</div>

<div class="working-steps">
  <h1 style="color: purple">This for sure works, i don't know why.....</h1>
</div>

<div class="working-steps-limit">
  <h1 style="color: purple">This works weird.....</h1>
</div>

<div class="delayed-animation">
  <h1 style="color: purple">This for sure works, i don't know why.....</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: To work more authentically like a typewriter needs a fixed width font, a stepping motion and timing related to the length of the line. Is a monospace font acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline-block` onto your wrapper divs. By default, the divs stretch completely across the screen, but adding the above makes them conform to the length of their contents.

If you want to hide the border before the animation starts, simply add `border-style: none` to your div and `border-style: solid` to the `0%` of your keyframes.

Comment: With wrapper divs do you refer to for example in the code pen the div `working-steps` or `return`? Or do you mean the div outside of that in my real page? Because if it's the first answer adding that to each div makes them go crazy and have one cursor for each div that starts in the same place. And if you mean the second one in my page i already have that. And adding `border-style: solid` works to delete the cursor at the start but makes a border at every writing animation :/

Comment: Moving the `border-right: .15em solid #EF6D6D` from the div to the from @keyframes and adding `border-style: none` to the div makes it. Ty

Comment: Sorry, I meant putting each of your `working-steps` and such in another div individually and having `inline-block` on those. You'll also need linebreaks or similar between them or else they'll clump together in a line.